# How to bind dependency injected system wrapper to play application controller?

Tags: playframework, dependency-injection, mocking, guice, inject

My Application depends on a custom class that inherits from trait SystemComponent.

```
package com.example 
trait SystemWrapper { ... }
trait MySystemWrapper extends SystemWrapper { ... } 

class RealSystemWrapper extends MySystemWrapper { dao: RealDAOFactory =>
  val blah = new MySystem("Production")
}
```

in my Application.scala injecting RealSystemWrapper works and compiles just fine but doesn't help me with testing:

```
class Application @Inject() (syswrap: RealSystemWrapper) extends Controller
{ 
 ...// use syswrap here
}
```

I would like to use a `MockedSystemWrapper extends SystemWrapper` with a mocked DAO factory, etc etc. Therefore I would like to inject the trait SystemWrapper like so

```
class Application @Inject() (syswrap: SystemWrapper) extends Controller 
{
```

but I get ProvisionException: No implementation was bound

```
1) No implementation for com.example.SystemWrapper was bound.
  while locating com.example.SystemComponent
    for parameter 0 at com.example.controllers.Application.<init>(Application.scala:25)
  while locating com.example.controllers.Application
    for parameter 1 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:27)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application
```

Play docs suggest I use `@ImplementedBy[classOf[RealSystemWrapper]]` decorator but that leaves me with the testing question: how do I change that at testing to `classOf[MockedSystemWrapper]`?

Answer (score 2):

As `Application` depends on a trait, you need to define the "binding" (ie. which concrete class to use). One approach is, as you described, the `@ImplementedBy` annotation. Another approach would be to define the binding in a module as described here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Programmatic-bindings

Now if you want to use a different instance in your test, that depends on your test setup. In the simplest case, you're instantiating `Application` directly in your test and therefore you can pass in the mock by hand. If you're running the entire application you class, then you can override the bindings (as described here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice#Override-bindings) or pass the overridden modules to the `WithApplication` helper (as shown here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithSpecs2)

Comment: This is my second question where they link to the doc. Believe me if the docs gave me what to write, i wouldn't be here. I've read all play/guice/and DI docs forwards and backwards several times. They leave a lot of gaps while at the same time seem to be talking about exactly what I need. It's kind of frustrating. I've given exact sample code, can I get some sample code back? How do I change WithApplication to include my MockedSystemWrapper? how do I use "around"?

Comment: Rephrased my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170769/my-play-applications-constructor-takes-an-argument-how-do-i-give-a-mocked-argu

Comment: @dlite922 please accept the answer here if it has helped.

Comment: I am still struggling. I'll post my code once it works.