# My Play Application's Constructor takes an argument, how do I give a mocked argument at Spec Test?

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, mocking, specs2

If my play application has something like this:

```
class Foo() extends Bar {} 

class Application @Inject (f: Foo) extends Controller {
  def index = Action { OK("Hi, Foo App") }
}
```

How do I change my spec test to accept MockedFoo class?

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])

class MockedFoo() extends Bar {}

class ApplicationTest(implicit ee: ExecutionEnv) extends Specification  {

  "Sending a GET request to index " should {

    "Respond with OK " in new WithApplication { //######## Inject MockedFoo
      val response = route(app, FakeRequest(GET, "/")).get
      status(response) mustEqual OK
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help:

Answer (score 0):

Copying from my own Gist: https://gist.github.com/rethab/01fde763d10f29273d43

First, create a helper class for convenience:

```
class WithFancyApp(lang: Lang = Lang.defaultLang,
                   overrideModules: Seq[GuiceableModule] = Seq()) extends
  WithApplication(
    app =
      new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
      .in(Environment(new File("."), getClass.getClassLoader, Mode.Test))
      .loadConfig(env => Configuration.load(env))
      .overrides(overrideModules:_*)
      .bindings()
      .build
 ) {

  implicit def messages: Messages = Messages(lang, app.injector.instanceOf[MessagesApi])

}
```

Usage:

```
"use the overridden bindigs" in new WithFancyApp(
       overrideModules = Seq(bind[MyInterface].to[MyImplementation])
) {
    // test stuff with all regular bindings plus the ones from above
}
```

Comment: I would rather not do a GuiceModule. Seems so much over-heard for something so simple: I need to pass in a different Bar implementation (MockedFoo) to my Application Constructor in Test. Guice Module can't be the only possible way!

Comment: There's an implicit conversion from `bind[MyInterface].to[MyImplementation]` to `GuiceableModule` so you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Where are your import lines?